# Woocommerce get selected variation from order object

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I am trying get variations from order object. This is my code:

```
// This is my order object.
global $order;

// I am getting items from order.
$items = $order->get_items();

// Get single item from items
foreach( $items as $item ) {
    // Get product id which i bought.
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

    // Get product object which i bought
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // This is my problem! It gets all variations. I want to gent only selected when customer was buying.
    $product_variation_name = $product->get_attribute( 'my-custom-variation' );
}
```

As i said. I am trying get selected variation from my bought order. But `$product->get_attribute` gets all variations.

My variation looks like this in product page:

```
<select name="variation" id="variation">
    <option value="pa_my-custom-variation">My Custom Variation</option>
    <option value="pa_other-variation">Other Variation</option>
    <option value="pa_other-variation-1">Other Variation 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should get the variation id from the item first then you get the variations and attributtes

this is working for me

```
 $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id(); 
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
    $variationName = ' ' . implode(" - ", $variation->get_variation_attributes());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].